Bamboo Maven builds failing
We are in the process of migrating to Bamboo to build and deploy our AEM projects, currently our repos exist on Bitbucket. We have Nexus repo setup at our enterprise level and the same has been configured in settings.xml (example: mavenrepo.company.com/nexus/content/groups/public) I have also defined an additional repo in my settings.xml as repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public.
Now when I run Maven build on my local machine, the builds work fine. But when I run on Bamboo, I run into following errors,
29-Apr-2024 11:34:57  [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
29-Apr-2024 11:34:57    [ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:jar:0.5.1 @
29-Apr-2024 11:34:57    [ERROR] Unknown packaging: content-package @ line 34, column 16
The line34, Column 16 of pom.xml it is complaining about I have the following, this POM is from ui.apps
content-package
When I try navigating to the Download URL (https://mavenrepo.company.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/jcr/vault/content-package-maven-plugin-parent/0.5.1/content-package-maven-plugin-parent-0.5.1.pom ) i get the below error
Path /com/day/jcr/vault/content-package-maven-plugin-parent/0.5.1/content-package-maven-plugin-parent-0.5.1.pom not found in group repository "Public Repositories" [id=public].
But I could see the pom exist under Adobe's repo (public)  https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/jcr/vault/content-package-maven-plugin-parent/0.5.1/content-package-maven-plugin-parent-0.5.1.pom
How can i go about resolving this error ?
On my local machine, I deleted the repos (content-package-maven-plugin and content-package-maven-plugin-parent) under .m2\repository\com\day\jcr\vault and when i ran the build i could see Maven downloaded the repos from Adobe repo instead of our company's Repo. But this doesnt happen on Bamboo, it always tries reaching Companys Repo. I cannot access our Bamboo's (.m2 repo or settings.xml).

Sounds like your repository manager (nexus) is not configured correctly either missing the needed repository or the configuration in your Maven build (settings.xml) is not correctly configured...

I checked with the support team of Nexus and they are seeing the artifacts available at the location  https://mavenrepo.company.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/jcr/vault/content-package-maven-plugin-parent/0.5.1/content-package-maven-plugin-parent-0.5.1.pom  not sure why it cannot download them.

Try adding the adobe-public profile to your .m2/settings.xml or run the build with mvn -P adobe-public 

I was able to resolve the issue by uploading the individual artifacts into Nexus repos. Thanks for all your suggestions, they helped me verify different aspects.
